# Inputs on how to achieve REST based interaction between Java and Python?

Tags: java, python, rest, api

I have a **Java** process which interacts with its REST API called from my program's UI. When I receive the API call, I end up calling the (non-REST based) **Python script(s)** which do a bunch of work and return me back the results which are returned back as API response.
- I wanted to convert this interaction of UI API -> JAVA -> calling python scripts to become end to end a REST one, so that in coming times it becomes immaterial which language I am using instead of Python.
- Any inputs on whats the best way of making the call end-to-end a REST based ?

Comment: What is your communication method between your UI and java?

Comment: Use a front end framework like Angular JS and have the rest api return results in JSON. The front end won't care what language the back end is written in and you can change languages whenever you'd like.

Comment: @Erik Jersey framework is used

Comment: @mba12 Sure. But my question is how to have Java and Python interact via REST. Is it more like JERSEY java making calls to Python Flask ?

Comment: @Rohan Jersey/Flask could work, yes. Keep in mind the python and java are not communicating directly with each other as they might if one process opened a socket to communicate directly with the other. In your Jersey/Flask example there is the http/json in the middle in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flask as a wrapper for converting your Python scripts into microservices. Then, call your Python scripts from Java by passing them a JSON string in a REST call.

For each python script, listen on a port between 50,000-65,000 and then send your Java-->Python REST calls to `http://127.0.0.1:50000`, `http://127.0.0.1:50001`, etc.

There really isn't a limit to how far you can break down your code, each function is a potential microservice. Try to encapsulate complexity in classes, create simple interfaces for these classes, and then expose these interfaces via REST. As a Java programmer I'm sure you will have no problem with this! Google "flask microservices example" for code samples to get yourself started.

It gets more complicated if your Java app doesn't block between calling each Python script, though. In that case you are using async calls or launching a new thread for each request.

(PS: There is a good article on microservices architecture [here](https://eng.uber.com/building-tincup/).)

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, in the future you might want to separate them from the same machine and use network to communicate.

You can use **http** requests.

Make a contract in java of which output you will provide to your python script (or any other language you will use) send the output as a json to your python script, so in that way you can easily change the language as long as you send the same json.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As of now, content is being passed as a JSON file (filesystem gets involved, no streaming). But, later on if I want to switch from Python to Java, that backbone doesn't exist. So, as per my understanding REST can do that. Therefore, how do i go about making the whole setup end-to-end a REST one ? Is it more like JERSEY java (current/extsing) making calls to Python Flask (in future) ?

Comment: I misunderstanding the 'end-to-end a REST one' . Your UI | Client | Server pipe is fine !